# React-Redux: this.props.data.map is not a function error

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

In my react app I am using API calls which should be authenticated by a token. so the first call is for getToken and then storing token in the session, but whenever I start my project it always throws an error on first run it(the error on the title)but if I refresh it, everything works.
Can somebody explain to me what I am missing is this a problem of Async Calls?

**Below are some part of my code**

**1).** This is where I call token and other required API for my page during load:

```
componentDidMount() {
 this.props.getToken('react@e-yantra.org','react007zxt');
  //sessionStorage.setItem('jwtToken', this.props.token);
   this.props.fetchStates();
   this.props.fetchVenues();
}
```

**2).** This is the action where I call fetch API:

```
import {
    FETCH_STATES,
    FETCH_VENUES
} from '../actions/types';

const token = sessionStorage.getItem('jwtToken');
const postheaders={
 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
};

export const getToken = (username,password) => dispatch=>{
        fetch('http://localhost:8001/api/getToken',{
          method: 'POST',
          headers: postheaders,
          body:JSON.stringify({username,password})
        })
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(token =>{
              let str=JSON.stringify(token.token).replace(/"/g,"");
              sessionStorage.setItem('jwtToken',str);
            });
    };


export const fetchStates = () => dispatch => {
    fetch(`http://localhost:8001/api/states?token=${token}`)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(states => dispatch({
            type: FETCH_STATES,
            payload: states
        }));
};


export const fetchVenues=()=>dispatch=>{
       fetch('http://localhost:8001/api/venues')
           .then(res => res.json())
           .then(venues => dispatch({
               type: FETCH_VENUES,
               payload: venues
           })
           );
};
```

**3).** Below is the part of render where I am using it and getting an error on the first run :

```
const stateItems = this.props.states.map(data => (
           <option key={data.id} value = {data.state} > {data.state} </option>
       ));

             ));
  const venueItems = this.props.venues.map(venue => (
                           <option key={venue.id} value = {venue.id} > {venue.college_name} </option>
                       ));
```

**Edit 1:** Problem is with token getting set in session store which is not available for the first API calls of states and venues.

```
http://localhost:8001/api/states?token=null 400 (Bad Request)
```

Comment: You are making an API call in componentDidMount and so on first render you data states and venues will not be available, provide an undefined check before using these values

Comment: i am using undefined check but it still no working

Comment: What exactly is the behaviour, can you please elaborate on that

Comment: I am using if(this.props.states!==undefined){ const stateItems= .....}

Comment: Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `states` of type `object` supplied

Comment: okkk, from the error it seems that states is being provided as an object, instead it should be an error. Either you have initialised it incorrectly in component state or the API is responding with an object and you need to convert it into an array in order to use map

Comment: yes, but why it works on 2nd render but not on first?

Comment: could be because in initialisation you set state to empty object while the API responds with data and state is set to an array which is expected

Comment: I am using propTypes and set it to array, also you can see action is there something wrong in that?

Comment: I just got the problem, its because the first run the token is not set to the session so the API didn't receive data first time. Do you know how to fetch token even before render?

Comment: http://localhost:8001/api/states?token=null 400 (Bad Request)

Comment: If token can be received synchronously, retrieve it in constructor else have a loading state and set loading to false once you receive token

Comment: I tried with constructor method it didn't work, I will try with state loading method

Comment: Can it be done if use token via state not via session?

Answer (score 3):

On the first render, the api call is being made, so it's most likely that when you are trying to access `this.props.states` it is `undefined` or empty.

A conditional to check it's availability should work for you, something on the lines of `this.props.states && this.props.states.map(..)`

You'll have to make sure other things work fine if this doesn't render until `this.props.states` gets populated with values.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Ho to check condition on 
this.props.states && this.props.states.map(..), like is it undefined?